# AndEngine - When I set sprites, the sprite's (0, 0) is the center of the sprite. How can I make it the bottom left like usual?

Tags: android, andengine

I am using the Anchor Center branch, and I have just found that most of the issues related to my game are for this reason. Is there a way to set sprites using the bottom left of the sprite rather then using (0, 0) as its center?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out!

.setAnchorCenter(0, 0);

Comment: before you go all crazy resetting your center, consider that the center anchor is better for both rotations and rough distance calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do that if the main change from GLES2 to GLES2 Anchor Center is the coordinate system where Y is inverted ?